# Odoo 14: There is an app in odoo app store select and deselect all companies for odoo v16 , how to make it compatible for version 14

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-16

There is an app in odoo app store select and deselect all companies for odoo v16 , how to make it compatible for version 14

[This is the result of the app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnwuv.jpg)

I've tried to change in javascript file and xml file but didn't affect

Comment: Could you provide more info of what app on the app store you refers too? Post the code of what you have tried to do and what are the issues that you are having